# Full text search in MongoDB, get native mongo driver Mikro ORM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mikro-orm

I am trying to use full text search in MongoDB using Mikro ORM. I have seen the issue where full text is implemented in SQL drivers but not for MongoDB. Is there any alternative or workaround for full text search in MongoDB? If not, how can I get native MongoDB driver in Mikro ORM like `getKnex` in SQL?

Comment: atlas support inverse lucene indexes, but it is not available in onpremise versions

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using Atlas. Do you know how to get MongoDB native driver in Mikro ORM?

Comment: maybe here there is some more info:  https://mikro-orm.io/docs/usage-with-mongo/